# Creating image with depth over 8 bit crashes visual studio

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am using the Emgu CV library to show images and do some math with them in a C# project. 
I am trying to read a picture from the filesystem, what works without problems if I set the depth of the picture to 8 bit. 
as soon as I want to save a larger image, visual studio crashes at the point, where instantiate the new image (see code). Crashing means the UI freezes and a message pops up int the Windows 10 info center, that says that visual studio is awaiting an internal process.

I tried to set the depth of the picture to 32 bit (int) and 16 bit (short). These types show the described problem. 8 bit (byte) does not show any problem. The image, I am using has a size of 69x44 pixels and a bitdepth of 32 bit (This is what explorer shows me).

```
private static readonly string imagePath = "C:/xxx/xxx/image.png";

var image1 = new Image<Gray, byte>( imagePath ); //works fine
var image2 = new Image<Gray, short>( imagePath ); //crashes visual studio
var image3 = new Image<Gray, int>( imagePath ); //crashes visual studio
```

I expect that image2 and image3 are stored as well as image1, because the image on my filesystem has the proper bitdetph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have a 32bit Bgra image? This means each pixel has 4 channels with each using 8bit. And Bgra stands for blue, green, red and alpha. That would be typical for png images as this format can encode an alpha channel.

Try:

```
var image1 = new Image<Bgra, byte>( imagePath );
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. It seems, that I had this kind of problem. I tried again using the Mat class, which told me, that the picutre has more than one channel.